# Setting Application variables to "" (instead of null) takes forever

Tags: asp-classic

I'm working on a legacy ASP application where we're having some intermittent problems with long response times on seemingly trivial page executions. Yesterday, I noticed that the handling of strings in the Application object seem to be related to our problems.

If, for example, I use the following line, the script takes approx. 30 seconds to run:

```
Application("loaded") = ""
```

On the other hand, if I set the value to null instead, the script executes immediately:

```
Application("loaded") = null
```

We're running IIS 7 on a Windows 2008 SP2 server.

Does anyone have experience with this? Any best practices we're missing? Thanks in advance!

Comment: I tried `Application("loaded") = ""` in its own script without any interference, and it still took a full 30 seconds.

Comment: Are you using `Application.Lock()` before assigning value ?

Comment: That's a good way to test, previous comment removed. About SearchAndResQ's question: also something to watch out for is if other scripts are locking things for extended periods of time (if your test script does not lock anything, but other scripts do).

Comment: Sorry for the long delay - yes, I use application.lock() before and application.unlock() after to ensure atomiticy.